# unable to parse a string of this format "1/29/2020 12:00:00 AM" into a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I am working on a SVC service, and when I run it locally I get the Date field as follow `30/01/2020 00:00:00` and I parse this string to be a `DateTime` as follow `(DateTime.ParseExact(i["ProjectLastUpdate"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'00':'00':'00'Z'"))`, since my local machine uses the United Kingdom regional setting. But when I host the service inside an Azure Web App, I start receiving the date string as follows:  `1/29/2020 12:00:00 AM`, and the service will raise this exception `“String was not recognized as a valid DateTime”` on the above code. So can anyone advice on this please? Can I standardize the date format on both local machine and azure? Also can I force my code to work on both environments?

Here is my full code, inside the service:-

```
using (ClientContext context = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
{
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", listItemID);
    ListItemCollection collListItem = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Project Update System").GetItems(camlQuery);
    context.Load(collListItem);
    foreach (ListItem i in collListItem)
    {
        var mydate = (DateTime.ParseExact(i["ProjectLastUpdate"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'00':'00':'00'Z'"));
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208497/discussion-on-question-by-test-test-unable-to-parse-a-string-of-this-format-1-2).

Answer (score 2):

The value of `i["ProjectLastUpdate"]` already *is* a `DateTime`, so there's no need to convert it to a string and then parse it back. So you can use a simple typecast:

```
var mydate = (DateTime) i["ProjectLastUpdate"].
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked 3 times already, with different details in each question. Let's put it all together :

- The data comes from SharePoint, using a CAML query.
- The `ProjectLastUpdate` is already a DateTime. (from comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60379587/how-i-can-convert-a-datetime-with-the-followg-format-2-24-2020-120000-am-int))
- The *real* question is how to compare this DateTime to a string in the ISO8601 format in UTC, ie `YYYY-MM-DD-THH:mm:ssZ`.
- Or is it, how to *filter* using a UTC date? This can be done in CAML, by adding the `StorageTZ='TRUE'` attribute to the filter value.

**Date Comparison**

The answer is to convert the comparison string to DateTime, not the DateTime to a string. Once this is done, we can just use `otherDate.Equals(spDate)` or `otherDate.CompareTo(spDate)`.

The SharePoint value is already a DateTime, boxed in an object. [DateTime.Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.equals?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_Equals_System_Object_) and [DateTime.CompareTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.compareto?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_CompareTo_System_Object_) have overloads that work with a boxed Datetime, so we don't even need to cast to `DateTime`.

We can use :

```
var myDate = (DateTime) i["ProjectLastUpdate"];
```

or just

```
var mydate = i["ProjectLastUpdate"];
```

What *does* matter, is parsing the comparison value. Things get interesting here.

[DateTime.Parse(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_) by itself can parse this string without trouble. It will return a *local* time though. In my timezone, GMT+2:00, this code :

```
var otherDate=DateTime.Parse("2020-02-25T00:00:00Z");
```

Returns a DateTime object whose `Kind` is `Local` and value `2020-02-25T02:00:00`.

SharePoint stored UTC datetime though. To get that, we need the [DateTime.Parse overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_) that accepts a `DateTimeStyles` parameter. This code :

```
var otherDate=DateTime.Parse("2020-02-25T00:00:00Z",null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

This returns a DateTime whose Kind is UTC and value `2020-02-25T00:00:00`.

**CAML Filtering using UTC**

The question [CAML query compare DateTime in UTC](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/244261/caml-query-compare-datetime-in-utc) asks how to query in UTC. By default, SharePoint converts the stored UTC to local time and this condition :

```
<Gt>
    <FieldRef Name='ProjectLastUpdate ' />
    <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2018-06-28T00:00:00Z</Value>
</Gt>
```

Would work on local time. To compare using UTC, we need to add `StorageTZ='TRUE` :

```
<Gt>
    <FieldRef Name='ProjectLastUpdate ' />
    <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' `StorageTZ='TRUE` Type='DateTime'>2018-06-28T00:00:00Z</Value>
</Gt>
```

On the other hand, if we only care about the *date*, we can simply ignore the time value :

```
<Gt>
    <FieldRef Name='ProjectLastUpdate ' />
    <Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' `StorageTZ='TRUE` Type='DateTime'>2018-06-28T00:00:00Z</Value>
</Gt>
```